# К kwargs обращаться через get(key)

Tags: python, методы, dict

мой ревьювер просит К kwargs обращаться через get(key) не могу понять как реализовать

```
class CategoryPostListView(MainPostListView):
    template_name = "blog/category.html"
    category = None

    def get_queryset(self):
        slug = self.kwargs["category_slug"]
        self.category = get_object_or_404(
            Category, slug=slug, is_published=True
        )
        return super().get_queryset().filter(category=self.category)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["category"] = self.category
        return context
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, это может выглядеть так:

```
def fun(**kwargs):
    print(kwargs.get('start', 'Здороваться нужно сначала!'), kwargs.get('end', 'А пока сказать?'), sep='; ')

fun(start='Привет')
fun(end='Пока')
fun(start='Привет', end='Пока')
```

```
Привет; А пока сказать?
Здороваться нужно сначала!; Пока
Привет; Пока
```